# Ghostscript: Convert PDF into CMYK EPS

Tags: ghostscript, eps, cmyk

is it possible to convert a PDF into a CMYK EPS using ghostscript?

The following command works fine - but the result is RGB I guess:

```
gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=epswrite -o test.eps test.pdf
```

This command:

```
gswin32c.exe \
   -sDEVICE=epswrite \
   -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK \
   -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK \
   -o test.eps \
    test.pdf
```

gives me the following error message

Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops

Thanks, 
Ronald

Comment: Have you tried to conver to a CMYK-PDF first, and then turn that one into EPS? Not sure if that would work, but it is worth a try. Otherwise, we'll have to wait for KenS to see this question -- he's one of the most authoritative people all things Ghostscript... :-)

Comment: @KenS: Do you see this? (Not sure if adding an '@KenS:' to the front of the comment makes this stand out in your portal page when you enter stackoverflow...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion pipitas but the PDF is already CMYK. Best, Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the answer is basically no. There are various tricks which work more or less, but nothing simple and reliable.

We will be reworking the colour code in pdfwrite/ps2write and colour conversion will be addressed at that time.

pipitas I had seen this post, but myOpenID was down again....

Comment: Thanks for your answer KenS. Is there any other tool which can convert PDF into CMYK EPS? Best regards, Ronald

Comment: At the moment, I'm afraid I don't know of one. You *might* be able to do it with Acrobat by saving the PDF as PostScript and then re-distilling using Distiller, with some cunning use of distiller params. Beyond that I'm afraid I don't know of anything. I would like to think the new colour code will be in the next version of GS but since it isn't started yet, I can't say for sure. Actually I'm somewhat surprised that a CMYK PDF woudl end up as RGB with epswrite. You could also try using ps2write to convert to PostScript, and then epswrite to convert the PostScript into an EPS.

Comment: "Currently" now is nearly two years ago. Did something change since then?

Comment: The colour code was reworked in thbe 9.10 release, and in the current release of Ghostscript the new code is enabled by default. You need to use the eps2write device (not epswrite) and set -dColorConverionStrategy=CMYK. So yes, something changed.